# Display default billing address selected in options. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, billing-address, billing

I want to display the default billing autoselected
in the dropdown menu https://prnt.sc/rmyqwo in checkout page
Magento 2

Answer (score 0):

Run this code in console i.e 
window.checkoutConfig.customerData.addresses 
you will see the list of address check which address is marked as default_billing: true use that key and add js code which will run once you click on next button after selecting shipping method or you can add in js once the checkout page load
reference
[image]

Comment: Thankyou john , i've run that code just now & saw address as default , what wil be the next step for me to prevent reloading this and billing section/address when i update/edit new billing address form ?

Comment: default billing address will be set by customer only from his/her account section once whatever they will select based on that address will become default you can use logic like `if(window.checkoutConfig.customerData.addresses.length > 0)
   {
    window.checkoutConfig.customerData.addresses.forEach(function(ele,index){
    if(ele.default_billing != undefined)
    {
     billing_inline = ele.inline;
    }
   });`

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal, did you get the solution for this?